# Threading and SqlFileStream. The process cannot access the file specified because it has been opened in another transaction

Tags: c#, multithreading, sql-server-2008, parallel.foreach, sqlfilestream

I am extracting content of the Files in SQL File Table. The following code works if I do not use Parallel.

**I am getting the following exception, when reading sql file stream simultaneously (Parallel).**

> The process cannot access the file specified because it has been opened in another transaction.

## **TL;DR:**

When reading a file from FileTable (using GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT) in a Parallel.ForEach I get the above exception.

## **Sample Code for you to try out:**

https://gist.github.com/NerdPad/6d9b399f2f5f5e5c6519

## **Longer Version:**

**Fetch Attachments, and extract content:**

```
var documents = new List<ExtractedContent>();
using (var ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
{
    var attachments = await dao.GetAttachmentsAsync();

    // Extract the content simultaneously
    // documents = attachments.ToDbDocuments().ToList(); // This works
    Parallel.ForEach(attachments, a => documents.Add(a.ToDbDocument())); // this doesn't

    ts.Complete();
}
```

**DAO Read File Table:**

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<SearchAttachment>> GetAttachmentsAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var commandStr = "....";

        IEnumerable<SearchAttachment> attachments = null;
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(this.DatabaseContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandStr, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                attachments = reader.ToSearchAttachments().ToList();
            }
        }

        return attachments;
    }
    catch (System.Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

**Create objects for each file:
The object contains a reference to the GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT**

```
public static IEnumerable<SearchAttachment> ToSearchAttachments(this SqlDataReader reader)
{
    if (!reader.HasRows)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    // Convert each row to SearchAttachment
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        yield return new SearchAttachment
        {
            ...
            ...
            UNCPath = reader.To<string>(Constants.UNCPath),
            ContentStream = reader.To<byte[]>(Constants.Stream) // GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT() 
            ...
            ...
        };
    }
}
```

**Read the file using SqlFileStream:**
**Exception is thrown here**

```
public static ExtractedContent ToDbDocument(this SearchAttachment attachment)
{
    // Read the file
    // Exception is thrown here
    using (var stream = new SqlFileStream(attachment.UNCPath, attachment.ContentStream, FileAccess.Read, FileOptions.SequentialScan, 4096))
    {
        ...
        // extract content from the file
    }

    ....
}
```

## **Update 1:**

According to [this](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/Posts/19400/filestream-and-database-transaction-isolation-levels.aspx) article it seems like it could be an Isolation level issue. Has anyone ever faced similar issue?

Comment: Try opening the file on the same thread that did the rest of the SQL. Maybe this is simply not allowed.

Comment: You are writing to  `documents` on multiple threads, `List<T>` is not thread safe and you can not do this (It is not likely the source of your problem but it is a problem)

Answer (score 4):

The transaction does not flow in to the `Parallel.ForEach`, you must manually bring the transaction in.

```
//Switched to a thread safe collection.
var documents = new ConcurrentQueue<ExtractedContent>();
using (var ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
{
    var attachments = await dao.GetAttachmentsAsync();
    //Grab a reference to the current transaction.
    var transaction = Transaction.Current;
    Parallel.ForEach(attachments, a =>
    {
        //Spawn a dependant clone of the transaction
        using (var depTs = transaction.DependentClone(DependentCloneOption.RollbackIfNotComplete))
        {
            documents.Enqueue(a.ToDbDocument());
            depTs.Complete();
        }
    });

    ts.Complete();
}
```

I also switched from `List<ExtractedContent>` to `ConcurrentQueue<ExtractedContent>` because you are not allowed call `.Add(` on a list from multiple threads at the same time.

Comment: Assuming the transaction is copied over, is concurrent SQL filestream access safe?

Comment: @usr Yes, that is one of the benefits of using [SQL filestreams](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993(v=sql.105).aspx), they can take part in transactions. The actual file access is done via UNC network shares to a transient path that exists for the lifetime of the transaction. It would be no different than opening two Read only `FileStream` objects to the same network path.

Comment: @usr Out of curiosity I checked the reference source. SqlFileStream is just a wrapper around a normal FileStream and a managed wrapper around a [FILE_FULL_EA_INFORMATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545793(v=vs.85).aspx) (The `byte[]` you pass in to the constructor is the data for that struct)

Comment: That's pretty conclusive assuming that the SQL Server file share can take concurrent access to the same file which seems likely.

Comment: Just to sure I verified the data again. There are no duplicates in the collection. So each thread should be accessing a different file.

Comment: This isn't working for me. Could you please check this gist that I created. https://gist.github.com/NerdPad/6d9b399f2f5f5e5c6519

Comment: Looks like it's an isolation level issue.